# Not able to find auto port in java 1.4

Tags: java, serial-port

The below code returns **false** in java 1.7 but returns **true** in java 1.4.
comm.jar is present under both directory: **Java\jre7\lib\ext**, and **\Java\jre1.4.2\lib\ext**.

```
Enumeration portList = null;
portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
System.out.println("portList.hasMoreElements(): " + portList.hasMoreElements());
```

The output is:

For Java 1.4:

```
portList.hasMoreElements(): true
```

For Java 1.7:

```
portList.hasMoreElements(): false
```

Need a help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

The earliest documentation I could find was for [Java 1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html). This means that it might not be fully supported in earlier java versions. Some of the functionality might not work at all while some could return different results as with your case.